# Compare version with different lengths in PHP

Tags: php, string, compare, version

Am I wrong or version_compare doesn't support comparing string/numbers having different "dot" length ?

Is there a quick way to compare the following without reinvent the wheel ?

```
version_compare(1.0, 1.0.0.0) => equal
version_compare(1.0, 1.0.0.1) => right is higher
version_compare(1.1, 1.0.0.1) => left is higher
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this;

```
  function versionCompare($a, $b) {

       $a = str_replace('.', '', $a);
       $b = str_replace('.', '', $b);

       $len = max(array(strlen($a), strlen($b)));


       $a = (int) str_pad($a, $len, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
       $b = (int) str_pad($b, $len, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);

       if ($a === $b) {
           // Versions are equal
       } elseif ($a > $b) {
           // First version is higher
       } else {
           // Last version is higher
       }
  }
```

Comment: Check my edit, forgot to add in the the `str_pad` :-)

Comment: Haha, made the same edit but yours is better as it doesn't hardcode length

Comment: Glad it helped, accept it so it can help others too! Merry christmas.

Comment: Sorry, I was under testing... It works fine, Txs. Mry Xmas..;-)

Comment: If you need to compare wildcards as well .. 
$a = str_replace('.*', '9', $a); $b = str_replace('.*', '9', $b);